# How to call a function on a specific time without push notification in iPhone OS4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, xcode4

I want to call a function in my application on a specific time without any alert or notification to user, how can i do this if the application is closed?

any ideas?

Thanks in advance 
Inam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is not running, you cannot "wake" it without a notification. If your application is still running you can keep it running if it regged as a voip, audio or location service.

/P

Comment: Thanks for the help, is there any alternative ??? is there any property in push notification that enable you to open app without popping-up a dialog?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think so. I have been looking for this as well for an alarm clock app which I maintain.

Comment: if you got any solution for this in future then please send it to me also at inam.inside@hotmail.com

Comment: I sure will. Don't forget to approve answers when you find them answering your question.